# Postherpetic neuralgia: Treat or suffer the pain (if you can suffer)?

Tags: pain, shingles, pain-tolerance, analgesics

Postherpetic neuralgia can be treated by various analgesics, but I'm not sure that I need them, actually I can suffer that pain quite well. But may be analgesics  still do something more then just "pain control" or may be "pain control" is more then just "pain control" and provide some real treatment, nerve's regulation? I afraid that analgesics will just hide the real situation (may be good for clinic, but not good for me).

Details: Shingles (ZSV) diagnosed 10 day before, treatment by valaciclovir finished, skin is sensitive but nice how it can be after shringles (wraps body around the left). It seems I have moderate problems with immune system (because of my chronic cough?) but not AIDS. Pain is major (burning, shots, cramps) but still is not something that I can't suffer. At least can try suffer for some period.

Answer (score 2):

I had shingles in the last quarter of 2013. It was on the facial and trigeminal nerves. There were times when it felt like someone was boring a hole in my ear with a dull drill bit and pouring 90% isopropyl alcohol on an open wound on my left cheek. It was damn painful.
I have been taking gabapentin every since, and I'm not sure NSAIDs would be very helpful. Besides, they have their own risks, not the least of which are heart and gastrointestinal problems. Gabapentin has been most helpful, and it doesn't seem like I've suffered any side affects.
As to whether you should treat or suffer, that's really a personal decision, but if the choice were between NSAIDs or pain and you could tolerate the pain, I'd forego the NSAIDs.